# Creating users/groups via PHP

Tags: linux, php, suexec, useradd

I'm creating an internal tool that needs a bit of cpanel/webmin type functionality, but this isn't a situation where I could use one of those

Right now I need to be able to create linux users, groups, and directories via PHP. Here's what I have right now:

copies of useradd/groupadd/chpasswd in a user's /bin, SUID'd by root. the permissions are setup so only root and a specific group can access them (the group that the user is in).

If I run this from command line it works fine, but I was hoping to use suexec to access these, but it seems as if PHP won't work with suexec unless I run it through CGI which I don't really wanna do.

I could also allow wwwrun to access these SUID'd binaries but that seems a little insecure to me.

What is my next step here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea. Use PAM to move the authdb into something like a database where you don't need to invoke system tools in order to make changes.

Comment: could you give me any links to put me in the right direction on something like this?

Comment: would PAM be used to allow users ftp/ssh access of specific directories, or would it be used to allow PHP to create users for that?